# How to find max and min lightness values of an image in opencv?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I need to calculate Dynamic range of an image. So that I need to calculate the max and min lightness values of an image. I need to do this using opencv. Any idea how to do this in opencv?

Comment: You can find the answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253589/how-to-get-the-max-value-from-n-dimensional-array-in-opencv

Comment: @OneManCrew So the 4th and 5th parameter will be min and max value of an image?

Comment: @OneManCrew Am using the second answer of the question you referred. But am getting Assertion failed.

Comment: @OneManCrew Assertion failed ((cn == 1 && (mask.empty() || mask.type() == CV_8U)) || (cn >= 1 && mask.empty() && !minIdx && !maxIdx)) in minMaxIdx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this might help:

```
 // find minimum intensity and location of minimum intensiy
void min_Loc(Mat* img, Point* minloc, double* minVal)
{
    Mat dst2gray;
    double maxVal;
    Point maxloc;
    cvtColor(*img, *img, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    minMaxLoc(*img, minVal, &maxVal,minloc,&maxloc); //find minimum and maximum intensities and their positions

}
```